# Running Spark on EC2, only one Executor is used (should be more)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I set up a Spark cluster with two m1.large (should have both 2 cores, right?) instances using the script provided by Spark. 
After days of solving multiple problems I finally managed to run my first Spark algorithm on EC2.

Sadly, I quickly realized, that the runtime of my algorithm did not scale with the number of executors I configured in my spark submit script. The runtime stays the same, even though I changed --master[1] to --master[2]. If I do this on my local machine, the runtime changes notably, so the problem should not be with the algorithm, I guess...

After looking at the Spark UI, my suspicions were proven correct, only one executor was used the whole time, even though I told the script to use more.

I read my data out from S3 like this: JavaRDD logData = sc.textFile("s3n://id:secret@danielssparkbucket/testFolder/file.csv").cache();"

My spark-submit script call looks like this: sudo /root/spark/bin/spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --verbose --master local[2] --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 2 /home/ec2-user/simple-project-1.0.jar

I split the RDD manually into 4 partitions.

Anybody an idea what went wrong? And can somebody tell me, what exacltly the --master local[2] sets up and where difference is with --num-executors 2 and --executor-cores 2?

Greetings,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--master local[2]` Means you will have 1 Spark process using 2 threads with driver/executor inside it (`PROCESS_LOCAL`). Also it means there will be only 1 executor, as every executor is designed to be a separate process.

With `--master local[2]` these parameters are not used:

> --num-executors 2 and --executor-cores 2;

If you have multiple nodes - you can setup Spark Standalone Cluster - [cluster-launch-scripts](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts)

Comment: Thank you for the information regarding my used variables. Sadly though, I am not used to Linux, Apache and scripts. Because of this I have some questions left:   1. how should this conf/slave file look like and where should I place it. It is written, that I should list the hostnames of my slaves, but in which format?                                                                                   2. Which command should I use with this script?                                                    3. How do I run the .jar file afterwards?

Comment: Ok I searched through some more stuff online. It turns out, the ec2-script I used provided by Spark already connected my master and my worker node (the conf/slave file is already filled). Additionally, they are both already started. If I use the sbin/start-all.sh script, he tells me both are running and I need to stop them first). So this means, that alle the things in your answer are already set up, how do I start it now properly?

Comment: @DanielTöws If your spark-defaults.conf already have spark.master property with spark:///host:port - your standalone cluster is already set up and you can drop `--master local[2]` option when you run spark-submit as spark.master is already set.

Comment: My current spark-submit command looks like this: sudo /root/spark/bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://54.153.31.74:7077 --class "SimpleApp" /home/ec2-user/simple-project-1.0.jar        But after telling me, that it was not a REST server  and that he falls back to the legacy submission gateway instead (whatever this means), I recive this error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ec2-user/simple-project-1.0.jar, somehow he does not find the .jar he should execute, even though it is from this computer that I start the script (connected via ssh).

Comment: First try to run test job:

Comment: .bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master spark://<spark master host>:7077 path/to/spark/examples/jar 100
(Spark examples jar is located in spark-2.0.1/examples/jars folder)